# Double verification - extra security?

Tags: architecture, system, verification

I am working for a travel agency customer. The customers booking system is delivering hotel prices to some intermediate systems we have developed (these systems can also get prices from third party providers) and from here the prices go to the homepage where customers can buy hotel nights. Recently there was a bug in the booking system so they send the middle system a hotel with price zero. Now they want us to put a check into midlle our system that verifies whether a hotel has a positive price. I think they should check their data before they are sending it to us and then send an error flag if the price is zero. They claim it gives added security that we have two checks, first in their booking system and then in our middle level system. Can you provide me with some argument that will convince our customer that it is enough to only put the verification in their booking system? Thanks.

Comment: Since the hotel prices delivering system is an external system for you and you do not have any control over it, ideally you should have checks at your own end.  Each such subsystem should have their own responsibilities for error checking. Its not right to assume that upstream systems shall behave correctly always. Tomorrow, the other third party providers might mess up with their code/config and that's going to impact your system in one or other way. I think its good to put a check at your end.

Comment: OK, that is a good argument. I will accept that we put additional checks into our system, thanks for putting another perspecitive on this.